# linked list gives this warnings

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new to C and trying to learn some linked list from a book. I try to compile this example code but get those warnings below.

**warnings**

> linkedlist.c:29:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘display’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>    display(&amity);
>    ^
>   linkedlist.c: At top level:
>   linkedlist.c:31:14: error: unknown type name ‘island’

thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){

  typedef struct island{
    char *name;
    char *opens;
    char *close;
    struct island *next;
  }island;

  island amity  = { "Amity" , "09:00", "17:00", NULL};
  island craggy  = { "Craggy" , "09:00", "17:00", NULL};
  island isla_nublar = { "isla Nublar" , "09:00", "17:00", NULL};
  island sutter  = { "Shutter" , "09:00", "17:00", NULL};


  amity.next = &craggy;
  craggy.next = &isla_nablar;
  isla_nabla.next = &shutter;


  island skull  = { "Skull" , "09:00", "17:00", NULL};
  isla_nabla.next = &skull;
  skull.next = &shutter;
  display(&amity);
}
void display(island *start){
  island *i = start;
  for(; i != NULL; i = i->next){
    printf("NAme: %s open : %s-%s\n", i->name,i->opens,i->close);
  }
}
```

Comment: The `typedef` should be at the top level instead of inside `main()` if you want to use it in `display()` too.

Comment: And You have many typo.

Comment: Fix like [this](http://ideone.com/9GsXri)